# Is there a way to access API response data before the response has completed?

Tags: rest, api, soap

Some APIs don't have pagination implemented. Is there a way to access the partial response and access available objects before the API call has completed? For example if the response is json and the data that has already been received is:

```json
{"objectarray": [
   {"Name": "test1"},
   {"Name": "test2"},
   {"Name":
```

The first 2 elements are already loaded and can parsed. Why wait for the whole response to complete?
I guess there some problems with this approach. Please share thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a code sample that does what I need. Is there a better way to do it? Please share thoughts.

```
     WebClient client = new WebClient();
     Stream str = client.OpenRead(<url>);
     using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(str)))
     {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
           if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
           {
              while (reader.Read())
              {
                 if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
                 {
                     var jsonObject = JObject.Load(reader);
                     var deserialized = jsonObject.ToObject<T>();
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
```